# Ransack search include parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm using gem 'ransack' to search records.

The page I'm programming starts with ONLY a dropdown to select `@department`.
After that, I want Ransack to search within `@department`.

I need to include an additional parameter `department=2` with the Ransack search parameters. (It works if I insert that into the browser URL).

Browser URL after I type in department=2

```
http://localhost:5000/departments/costfuture?department=2&utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bid_eq%5D=&q%5Bproject_year_eq%5D=&q%5Boriginal_year_eq%5D=&q%5Bclient_id_eq%5D=43&q%5Blocation_name_cont%5D=&q%5Bproject_name_cont%5D=&q%5Bcoststatus_id_in%5D%5B%5D=&q%5Bcoststatus_id_not_in%5D%5B%5D=&q%5Brebudget_true%5D=0&q%5Bnew_true%5D=0&q%5Bconstruction_true%5D=0&q%5Bmaintenance_true%5D=0&commit=Search
```

This is the controller:

```
  def costfuture

    @departments = current_user.contact.departments
    if params[:department]
      @department = Department.find(params[:department])
      @search = @department.costprojects.future.search(params[:q])
      @costprojects = @search.result.order(:department_priority)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @departments }
    end
  end
```

I tried this in the view:

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: departments_costfuture_path(:department => @department.id) do |f| %>
```

But, the resulting URL is missing the `department=2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass the `department` option through to Ransack, you can do this with a hidden field within your `search_form_for`:

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: departments_costfuture_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :department_eq, value: @department.id %>
  <%# Other form code here %>
<% end %>
```

But if you want to search a particular department, then it's better to use Rails routes for that. You can generate URLs like `/departments/2/costfuture` by modifying [`config/routes.rb`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
resources :departments do
  get 'costfutures', on: :member
end
```

Now you can use the resulting URL helper to generate links that will set `params[:id]`, and you can use that to retrieve `@department`.

Comment: Thanks for the help - but, that line gives me "undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum"

Comment: That's going to be tricky to track down without seeing the full error & your controller action (and maybe your model definition too). Could you add those to your question, please?

Comment: This worked in the view `<%= f.hidden_field :department_eq, :value => @department.id %>`. But, I need to extract the department=x from the `params[:q]`. Do know how to do that?

Comment: This worked in the controller - to get the hidden department_eq - `      @department = params[:q][:department_eq]`

Comment: Thanks for the updates – I've added some more details to my answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using `hidden_field_tag` inside `search_form_for`.

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: departments_costfuture_path do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :department, @department.id %>
  <%= f.search_field :last_name_or_first_name_cont %>
<% end %>
```

Then `params[:department]` and `params[:search]` will be accessible in the controller.